# How to control smart bulbs using both the wall light switch and using voice?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, smart-lights

I want to be able to turn my smart lights on by using Alexa and my voice and the wall switch. Example like I turn it off by voice and then be able to turn it on by the switch and vice versa

Comment: If you only have a few switches, then Kalyan's answer is the way to go.  If you want to do more, then look at whole house solutions with a dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the wall switch to one of the smart ones.
This one, for example:
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/tp-link-tapo-smart-wi-fi-light-switch-with-matter-white/6543836.p?skuId=6543836  (I am not affiliated with the manufacturer or the seller - just an example.)
You maybe able to find some light bulbs that will work with simple (I dont want to call them dumb just because they are not smart!) switches in some strange ways such as toggle state by quick on, off. I'd seen one long ago, but I could not find it now.
Best of luck. Let us know what you tried and how it went.